# How to make button appear on hover when you hover over a whole table row?

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm running into a problem in my HTML code. I am trying to display a button when you hover over a row in a table. Right now the button only displays when you hover near it but I need it to show when you hover over anywhere on that row. Can anyone help explain how to do this?

```css
.button {
  opacity: 0;
}

.button:hover {
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <div class="button">
      <a href="#"></a>
    </div>
    <td><img src="/app/images/todo/todos_incomplete_blue.svg" /></td>
    <td>Make a To Do List</td>
    <td>Me Myself and I</td>
    <td>Whenever I want</td>
    <td>69%</td>
    <td>
      <div class="button">
        <img src="/app/images/master/actions_btn.svg" />
        <a href="#"></a>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you add the CSS relevant to the button display on hover to your question?

Comment: .button {
    opacity: 0;
}
.button:hover {
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 1;
}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right now, a button will only show when you hover over it directly. In order to show a button when its table row is hovered, set your CSS definition to target buttons that are inside of hovered rows:

```
tr:hover .button { ... }
```

Also:

1. `<div>` elements that are inside `<tr>` but not `<td>` are invalid, per the [permitted content of `<tr>` elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr). I have removed them, but you could wrap them in `<td>` elements if you need them.
2. I took the liberty of putting the `.button` images inside their `<a>` elements, although I'm not sure that's what you intended.
3. I noticed that the hover effect doesn't work over spaces between cells, which causes gaps in the hover area. So I set [`border-collapse:collapse;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse) and padding the cells individually.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  padding: 5px;
}

.button {
  opacity: 0;
}

tr:hover .button {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/30x20/" width="30" height="20" /></td>
    <td>Make a To Do List</td>
    <td>Me Myself and I</td>
    <td>Whenever I want</td>
    <td>69%</td>
    <td>
      <div class="button">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/30x20/" width="30" height="20" />
        </a>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/30x20/" width="30" height="20" /></td>
    <td>Make a To Do List</td>
    <td>Me Myself and I</td>
    <td>Whenever I want</td>
    <td>69%</td>
    <td>
      <div class="button">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/30x20/" width="30" height="20" />
        </a>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's my understanding that from explanation

> I am trying to display a button

that initially it is hidden? If so, just [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) hover over a button with jQuery.

So, lets say wee add `ID` to : `<tr id="myrow">` and in `<div class="button">` we also add `ID`: `<div class="button" id="mybtn">`

Then in jQuery we have:

```
$("#myrow").mouseover(function() {
   $("#mybtn").show() // if it was hidden show it
   $("#mybtn").trigger("mouseover"); // trigger as if mybtn was mouseovered
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but I can't use JS or jQuery right now. I just joined a company as a co-op and this is my starter project and they told me I only need to use html and css to complete the project.